# Trying to run 64-bit steam game through wine (mac)

Tags: mac, 64-bit, wine, steam

I'm incredibly new to Wine so if the answer to this is incredibly obvious, well thanks anyway.

So I installed Wine 3.0, and then I installed the Windows Steam client by double clicking the installer. It took me a while to figure out how to find the installed Steam client, but anyway. It works, and I can run *some* games, although some of them have some graphical glitches. :(

Anyway, so I tried to run a new game and it said I had to be on a 64-bit operating system. I have no idea how to make the client think that I am in fact in 64-bit though. Anyone know?

Comment: Set the WINEARCH environment variable to win32 i.e. export WINEARCH=win64

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/136714/how-to-force-wine-into-acting-like-32-bit-windows-on-64-bit-ubuntu

Comment: I copied and pasted a comment, failed to edit it, your Setting the variable to 64-but but it’s possible to configure for both.